# How to add a button to the title bar of an Avalon LayoutAnchorable?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, avalondock

Is it possible to add an additional button to an `LayoutAnchorable` of Avalon 2.0 version?
I was able to add a button to a native Windows' title bar, but the `LayoutAnchorable` has a completely different function.

Comment: Please make sure you have read the [ask] topics to get informed how to ask a question. Also, show us a [mcve] and/or the efforts you have so far.